# In DynamoDB TransactWriteItems ConditionCheck in same item as UpdateItem

Tags: amazon-web-services, transactions, amazon-dynamodb

In a planning system thousands of users compete simultaneously for the same time slots, stored in DynamoDB.
When a user tries to reserve a time slot, a TransactWriteItems should:

- ConditionCheck whether the slot is still available, and if it is
- UpdateItem to reserve the time slot for this user.

However, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/transaction-apis.html#transaction-isolation says "you can't perform a ConditionCheck and also an Update action on the same item in the same transaction."

How can I make sure that a user can only reserve a time slot that's not (shortly before) reserved by someone else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don’t need a transaction. You can just put the item to reserve the time slot and include a condition expression that it fails if it was already taken.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html